# Is it possible to restrict PHP form submission to a region/country?

Tags: php, forms

Simple PHP form.

**Is it possible to restrict the form submission to a specific region/country?** If so, how?

In this case the US.

I'm unable to find anything related to this. All I'm finding is restricting double-submit or using captchas.

Yes, I have a CAPTCHA, but humans get around it. I am already pulling the users IP, can I check that against a database somewhere? Or pull more than just the IP and run `strpos()` against it?

I'd like the form to work for anyone in the US, but display a message if the user is not located in the US. Or possibly display a stronger, more annoying captcha.

I can check domains in *some cases* but domains alone aren't specific enough.

Comment: This is _not_ possible in a reliable way. There are some options, but they are all vague, delivering false positives and negatives.

Comment: Maxmind GeoIP provides this and has a free "lite" version, but it will never be perfect and is of course defeatable with a proxy service or US-based VPN.  https://www.maxmind.com/en/home

Comment: I realize *nothing* would be perfect because proxies exist. But even a small step would be beneficial.

Comment: you could use free service  to search the geolocation of IP addresses [https://freegeoip.net/ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a GeoIP API such as freegeoip.net.
Whilst the above mentioned API can provide results in other formats, I prefer to use JSON as it is more simple to handle in PHP.

```
freegeoip.net/json/{IP_or_hostname}
```

With this, you can do

```
$geoipjson = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.freegeoip.net/json/" .$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]));
$country = $geoipjson->country_code;
if(!$country == "US") {
    die("Sorry, this form is not available for non-US users.");
}
else {
    // PHP handling goes here.
}
```

Edit:

If you wanted to lock down really hard, then you could also use a tool like https://getipintel.net/#API to check for proxies. From my experience it is pretty accurate; but this will not stop VPNs on a residential ISP block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`geoip` library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php) to get information regarding the ip of the user who visits your website:

```
$gi = geoip_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\n";

echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\n";

geoip_close($gi);
```

You will need to download the GeoLite library (which is free) from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/install/city/

MaxMind also released a newer version of the php's GeoIP lib, which called GeoIP2-php and can be found here: http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/
The database for GeoIP2 is available to download here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

The GeoIP2 lib is object oriented:

```
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

// This creates the Reader object, which should be reused across
// lookups.
$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');

// Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
// "country".
$record = $reader->city('128.101.101.101');

print($record->country->isoCode . "\n"); // 'US'
print($record->country->name . "\n"); // 'United States'
print($record->country->names['zh-CN'] . "\n"); // '美国'

print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name . "\n"); // 'Minnesota'
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode . "\n"); // 'MN'

print($record->city->name . "\n"); // 'Minneapolis'

print($record->postal->code . "\n"); // '55455'

print($record->location->latitude . "\n"); // 44.9733
print($record->location->longitude . "\n"); // -93.2323
```